# Cannot access subclass properties even when I export it as it's own type in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

At present I am unable to access any of the properties from the "Eagle" class. I have imported my "AnyBird" type but when I try and use properties off of specifically "Eagle" it isn't recognized at all. It only sees the properties from "Bird".

I'd say "Just import Eagle as the type" but I need to have other more specialized types accepted as well. Like "Doves", "Pidgeons", "Chickens" for example. It needs to be extendable so I wanted to concatenate all of the types under "AnyBird".

Help would be super appreciated!

```
export type AnyBird = Bird | Eagle ;

export interface Eagle extends Bird {
    energyGain: number;
    heatGain: number;
    energyCost: number;
    heatCost: number;
}


export interface Bird {
    id: number; 
    job: number;
    jobSpecificId: number;
    level: number;
}
```

---

An example would be in a separate file I'd be like:

```
import { AnyBird } from './common/skills/SpecialBirdsFile';

interface Props {
    someBird: AnyBird;
}


export default class BirdThing extends Component<Props, State> {
    state = {}
    render() { 
        let {someBird} = this.props;
        <div>
            {allBirds.id} <-- WORKS!!!!!!
            {allBirds.energyGain} <---- FAILS! Cannot be found.
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: this may help https://catchts.com/unions

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using a union type, where one of the types is a superset of the other, one way to solve this is by checking which type it is when you use the object.

For example, you can write a function called `isEagle` implemented something like this:

```js
function isEagle(obj: any): obj is Eagle {
   // however you'd check if this is an "Eagle" object. Ex:
   return obj.hasOwnProperty('energyGain')
}
```

To use the properties on `Eagle`, you'd call your function like this:

```js
const myBird: AnyBird = { ... };

if (isEagle(myBird)) {
   // properties of Eagle are available here
} else {
   // Just a base Bird object.
}
```